# C: Why does converting an int to float output 0.000?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have been working on this quiz: https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-quiz-pointers-addresses/

and don´t understand why casting an int to a float would output 0.000000

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
            int i = 10;
            void *p = &i;
            printf("%f\n", *(float*)p);
            return 0;
    }
```

Expected output: 10.000000

Actual output: 0.000000

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: "*casting an int to a float*" you are not doing that. You are casting the *address* (`p`)  of an `int` to the *address* of a `float`. This is something completely different.

Comment: violation of strict aliasing results in undefined behaviour, in which any result can happen

Comment: Note that answer given on quiz is incorrect.

Comment: It's indeed bewildering: The correct answer is even listed (b) but the incorrect one is given as solution (d) with no explanation..

Answer (score 4):

You're not casting an `int` to a `float`.

You're *attempting* to cast an `int*` to a `float*`.

The language does not allow you to do that and as such the behaviour of your code is *undefined*. The rationale is to afford maximum flexibility for architectures supporting C: they might put `float` data in a different memory location to `int` data.

Comment: can you give more information or examples of systems that `put float data in a different memory location to int data` ?

Comment: @user2162550: From memory some of the Intel 286 machines with a separate math co-processor (early 1990s) used to do this.

Comment: @Bathsheba The "different memory location" can be relevant when the format specifier for `printf()` mismatches (printf looks in the wrong location then), but not in the given case.

Comment: @user2162550 Imagine a system where `float` values have to be aligned on a multiple of four bytes, but an `int` has less restrictive alignment requirements, like a multiple of two bytes or any address at all.  On such a system, the posted code would fail if the `int i` were not aligned properly for a `float`.  For many, many, many examples, just Google [`SIGBUS` SPARC](https://www.google.com/search?q=sigbus+sparc).